# Cypress oidc login flow fails on the second login and returns 403

Tags: angular, authentication, cypress, openid-connect, http-status-code-403

Having

1. website that I test with cypress
2. cypress test that logs in via an other domain (oauth.b2beyond.org)

```
import {getAppCardTitles, getAppWrapper, getLoginButton} from "../support/app.po";

describe("b2beyond - logged in - start-page", () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.visit("/");
    getLoginButton().click();
    // @ts-ignore
    cy.login('***', '***');
  });

  it("Logged in - should show start page", () => {
    cy.reload(true);
    getAppWrapper().get("span[title]").contains("B2Beyond platform");
    getAppCardTitles().should(param => {
      expect(param).to.have.length(4);
    });
  });

  it("Logged in - should show start page second try", () => {
    cy.reload(true);
    getAppWrapper().get("span[title]").contains("B2Beyond platform");
    getAppCardTitles().should(param => {
      expect(param).to.have.length(4);
    });
  });
});
```

The command used for the login uses the **cy.origin** function to set the origin of the login domain.

```
Cypress.Commands.add("login", (username: string, password: string) => {
  const args = { username, password }
  cy.origin('oauth.b2beyond.org', { args }, ({ username, password }) => {
    cy.get('#usernameLogin').type(username);
    cy.get('#passwordLogin').type(password);
    cy.get('input[type="submit"]').first().click();
  });
});
```

Problem:

The first test is executed correctly, but the second test redirects and resolves in a http 403 status.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was running the tests against a service-worker enabled frontend. After disabling the sevice-worker in the e2e test all was good.